# Understanding 「あの後のオヤジとあれからどうだった？」

Tags: translation, particle-と

From the second episode of Death Note, a classroom a student says to another student:

> って**あの後のオヤジと**あれからどうだった？

1. I'm curious about this `<NOUN>と...<COPULA>` usage here. Is this slang for something else, or is it considered grammatical? Is と just the particle meaning "with", in this context?
2. あの後のオヤジ means "afterward's old man"? I assume it means something like "the old man (placed in time after something just happened)"?

Is a good translation something like

> After that thing happened (あれの後), what happened with (と) the old man?

Answer (score 2):

> あの後のオヤジとあれからどうだった？
> How was it with the old man after that?

1. Yes it's と meaning "(together) with". But note that "what happened with ～" does not necessarily carry the meaning of this と, especially when it marks an event or situation. A more explicit translation would be "What happened between you and the old man?"

   - 彼に何があったの?
     What happened to him?
   - 彼と何があったの?
     What happened between you and him?
2. Yes, あの後のオヤジ is a noun phrase, "the old man after that". Another similar examples would be:

   - 当時の私
     the me back then
   - 将来のあなた
     the future you
   - 10歳のときの彼女
     her when she was 10

Comment: How would I distinguish "her when I was 10" from "her when *she* was 10"? (Or would that just be 10歳の彼女 "the 10-year-old her"?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry, "I" was a typo.